# Efficiently update values held in scoring matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

I am continuously calculating correlation matrices where each time the order of the underlying data is randomized. When a correlation score with randomized data is greater than or equal to the original correlation determined with ordered data, I would like to update the corresponding cell in a scoring matrix with +1. (All cells begin as zeroes in the scoring matrix).

Due to the size of the matrices I am dealing with `shape = (3681, 12709)`, I would like to find out an efficient way of doing this. So far, what I have is inefficient and takes too long. I wonder if there is a matrix-operation style approach to this rather than iterating, as I am currently doing below:

```
for i, j in product(data_sorted.index, data_sorted.columns):

    # if random correlation is as good as or better than sorted correlation
    if data_random.loc[i, j] >= data_sorted.loc[i, j]:

        # update scoring matrix
        scoring_matrix[sorted_index_list.index(i)][sorted_column_list.index(j)] += 1
```

I have crudely timed this approach and found that doing this for a single line of my matrix will take roughly 4.2 seconds which seems excessive.

Any help would he much obliged.

Comment: At a first guess, converting `sorted_index_list` and `sorted_column_list` into dicts will probably help, as you'll be able to look up `i` and `j`'s respective locations faster.

Comment: What is the shape of `scoring_matrix` in relation to your data?

Comment: Hi both. Marius, thanks, I will give that a go and report what I find. @chrisb scoring_matrix has the same shape as the data, i.e. for each cell in the data (which would hold a correlation coefficient score measured between a pair of variables) there is a cell in the scoring matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming everything has the same indices, this should work as expected and be pretty quick.

```
scoring_matrix += (data_random >= data_sorted).astype(int)
```

Comment: You sir are the greatest person in the world for this answer. It has taken my operation from hours to seconds. Marked as correct. Thank-you very much.